A disguised ship with modern tech in the Age of Sail
Premise: a large group of people with a technological base equivalent to modern times appears on an isolated island in the Indian Ocean around 1750 or so. The aliens/gods/whoever responsible for this Island in the Sea of Time situation have provided their test subjects with sufficient raw materials and automated factories that they don't have to worry about maintaining their early 21st Century lifestyle, but at the same time not giving them enough to be able to simply take over the world.
The leadership of the island decides they want to make contact with existing nations in order to gather intelligence, but to do so in the guise of a contemporary peer. To that end, they build a vessel that appears, from relatively close range--say looking out at it anchored in a harbour--to be a large frigate. A single gun deck with 36 guns, full sail rig, and so on.
They, not being stupid, cheat when building the ship. They want to stuff as much modern tech and materials as they can into it to assure crew safety and combat effectiveness. You can assume they allow no one aboard, so free rein on the inside where no one can see, such as electrical lighting, pumps, powered winches, and so on. On the outside, light high tensile strength ropes and sail material and such that won't be that visibly different from what a normal ship of the time would have. Modern communications and such is a given.
So what could be some of the things they could do that would give this wolf in a much weaker wolf's clothing the biggest advantage if they had to engage an actual 1750s-ish ship in combat and not give up the game if a third party happened to be watching nearby?

Hmm, asking for a list of undefined length - what do we do with questions that want brainstorming and or story ideas...? Perhaps we recommend the Bright, shiny and all new story-teller's corner.

"if a third party happened to be watching nearby" - watching a ship when it's anchored, or when it is engaged in combat?

While I agree with the duplicate assignment, I'm going to vote Needs More Focus. Open-ended questions, especially those that lead to all answers having equal value, are prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. You're obligated to ask with the intent of selecting a best answer (even if you never do). But to be blunt... good grief, you've a ship stocked with modern weapons from automatic machine guns to small naval canon on a ship that's effectively armored against all takers with an infinite water supply and the ability to restock at will. Isn't that enough? Dead men tell no tales.


Steel.
Steel keel, steel hull, steel masts and steel yards. You may put a veneer of wood on the outside, maybe possibly.
Mid-18th century people knew what steel was, they were aware that in principle one could make a steel ship; the one thing that they didn't have was the ability to make good steel in quantity. Your all-steel ship won't appear as miraculous; it will appear as being made by either enormously rich people or else by people with vastly superior metallurgy. The all-steel ship might even be an excellent starting point for commercial negotiations.
A modern hull design will also work wonders for your speed.

Breech-loading late 19th to early 20th century guns with automatic gun-laying.
Mid-18th century gunnery was atrocious even by late 19th standards. A mid-18th century ship had between very little and no hope of hitting an enemy ship at half a mile; all naval engagements took place at basically point-blank range, under 100 yards or meters, and most often under 50 yards, meters, whatever.
You don't even need early 20th century naval guns. Semi-modern cannon like the famous French 75 mm field gun, with their hydro-pneumatic recoil mechanism, would provide a tremendous advantage in rate of fire. If directed by even the most primitive automatic fire control systems with a computerised director, of the level they had available in the First World War, they would make your ship invincible. You will be able to engage the enemy at ten times their effective range. Your modern-ish shells will render mid-18th century wooden ships into firewood. Their slow inert cannon balls will have minimal effect on your steel hull, masts and yards.

Schooner.
Don't make your ship square-rigged; make it a schooner.
Square sails are basically impossible to automate, and they cannot be operated from the deck. Square-rigged ships need enormous crews to work the sails, which makes them very crowded, require enormous amounts of victuals, and in general makes life aboard extremely unpleasant. By contrast, a schooner rig can be operated from the deck, can be easily adapted to use powered winches and computerized automation. Since you have breech-loading guns, your gun crews can be much smaller than what they used for their massive muzzle-loaders with no recoil mechanisms.
With a schooner rig you will be able to sail much closer into the wind than any square rigged ship could even dream of. Yes, a square rigged frigate might, just might, hope to catch you in a chase to windward, but you have a modern design hull which gives you a speed advantage, and after all you don't have to oblige the lumbering square rigger and run downwind; in a cross wind you will leave it cleanly behind.

Evaporator.
The major limitation of patrol duration for pre-modern ships was the need to carry sufficient fresh water for the crew. Adding an evaporator to produce fresh water on demand would free your ship from needing to replenish its water supply, and it wouldn't even seem outlandish to mid-18th century people. They knew perfectly well that one could distil sea water; their stills were just too ineffective to be practical in marine applications.

A small diesel engine.
You don't need a large diesel engine. All you need is a tiny marine diesel, 100 or 200 HP or so, capable to push your ship at maybe 3 knots. Being capable to maneuver in a dead calm would be very advantageous. Such an engine is not visible from the outside at all, and it would be a great force multiplier.
You will need the diesel anyway for your generator to power your electric lights, electric stowe, evaporator, navigation system, radar, and automatic gun laying system.

Modern chronometers and an inertial navigation unit.
Marine chronometers were invented in 1761. Without a marine chronometer, ships could not determine their position at sea; they had to use navigation methods which did not rely on knowing precisely where the ship was. With modern chronometers and an inertial navigation unit you can be certain of your position within one mile at all times.

Radar.
Radar systems don't have to be big and easily visible. A miniaturized radar system of the kind used in advanced driver-assistance system will be more than plenty for your needs when you are competing with mid-18th century wooden sailing ships.

Fathometer.
A continuously running fathometer will protect your ship against most unexpected shoals, rocks, and other submerged obstacles.


And, of course, you will have modern binoculars, night vision systems, small arms, etc. etc.

What about a Chinese junk rig?  How would it compare to a schooner rig?  If they were planning to gather intelligence in China a junk rig would look more normal, while if they were planning to gather intelligence in western seaports a schooner rig would look more normal.  Were there schooners as large as large frigates in 1750, or would a schooner that large seem out of place?

Computer-Aided Carriages, Rifling, and Better Powder
Typical engagement ranges during the 1700s were in the order of >200 metres.  This wasn't because cannon couldn't fire farther, but because reliable targeting when a ship was rolling, it and its target were moving, and vision was obscured by gunsmoke or weather was very difficult.
But your surprise ship is not so limited.  Just because the guns need to look, at a distance, like standard cannon doesn't mean you can't take advantage of more modern refinements.  Rifling, breech loading, and computerized targeting would mean your frigate could engage the enemy beyond a range at which they could meaningfully respond.  The muzzles might look like cast-iron cannon, but everything inside the gunport could look very odd (to a contemporary sailor) indeed.
Modern propellant chemistry would also give you an enormous range advantage, but you'd have to temper that so as not to seem too suspicious, and also mix in something that would produce an appropriate cloud of smoke.
Incendiary Small-Arms Ammo or Rockets
No one observing a naval engagement is going to notice that someone leaning out a gun port or in a redoubt on the deck is using a very unusual looking musket.  Once gunsmoke is in the air, no one is going to think anything strange of fires being set on the target ship.  There will be a surprising number, but combat is strange that way.
Given the very limited visibility available to people with 1750s optics, you could even have small incendiary rockets in man-portable launchers.  Big explosions would be noticeable.  Fires starting on a ship under fire, much less suspicious.  But if modern accelerants are involved, awfully hard for the target ship's crew to subdue the flames.
Depending on Budget, Armour
You could go so far as to make a reverse-ironclad.  Being holed beneath the waterline could be made entirely impossible by disguising armour as coppering, and then thin armour (advanced metallurgy) on the inside of the decks could prevent the penetration of round shot or the splintering of the wooden hull killing crew.
On that note:
Theatrics
If there is an observer expected to survive, it would behoove the people manning the faux-Frigate to have squibs, smoke charges, and sound effects to feign greater damage suffered than they would legitimately expect.
Edit:
An important point would be that if an engagement is entered into, your crew would probably have to offer no quarter.  It is presumably not worth the verisimilitude to have crew members die to preserve the illusion, so you'd be cheating hard enough that any experienced sailor on the other side is going to see way too many coincidences to let it slide.  Having surviving sailors from the other ship would thus be an unacceptable risk to the desired secrecy of your actual tech levels.  Your ship not acknowledging when the opposing side strikes their colours is not going to be well-received by an observer, though, so entering into a fight should be a last resort.

Definitely add fused explosive shells to the mix alongside round shot the idea would be to put a no more than one or two explosive shells into every second or third salvo fired by the Q-ship. Have the first ranging salvos deliberate be a little 'off' target to disguise just how accurate they really are then engage them with conventional solid shot for the second and and or third salvos before bringing explosive filled round into the mix but no more than a couple per salvo.

Others have given great answers - especially radar directed guns.
However there are 2 things that would be buried deep in the ship, but contribute to crew survivability:
Refrigerated food stores and a modern infirmary
Fresh food and modern medicine. These two will do more to decrease the loss of life for the average sailor than anything else.
Even in combat, the majority of wounds weren't immediately fatal, but due to infection and other complications - something that today would leave a nasty scar and a great story was a matter of life and death back then.
Things like Scurvy, malnutrition etc. Which both hampered recovery and also made sailing miserable - with modern food stores would prevent food from spoiling and allow them be healthier in general which allows for better survivability.

Bad idea.
The best disguise is no disguise. Make a very good ship, use tech that is not obvious at a glance but not impossible even under scrutiny.
Don't make 36 gun ship, make a slup. As small as it makes sense for open sea. If all you want is drop and pickup people, don't spend resources on it. The more you have to hide the worse.

You can assume they allow no one aboard, so free rein on the inside where no one can see, such as electrical lighting, pumps, powered winches, and so on.

No you can't. In any port port authorities likely to visit. Port fees, tariffs, etc. The moment they walk into your bowling alley, inspectors will feel something is wrong. Military at open sea may want to inspect you. Unless you are prepared to murder thousands to keep secrets, have no secrets.
About decisive advantage - have a couple of really good guns. Authentic looking but extremely precise. Shells - iron balls from the outside, but made with precision and high explosives. Let's say you have 75% chance to hit the magazine of the enemy with the first shot at 1 km. You are unassailable.
And make the thing really fast. Advanced hull and sail design. Easy. Light ship can be very fast.
Also, make a submarine and let it pull your sloop around when no one is looking. Put your crew there so they can chill in comfort while in route. If you sloop sinks - return to island and build another one. Avoid other ships in open sea. Avoid storms. Easy sailing.
Actually, forget the sloop. You want to deliver people back and forth, just use the submarine and equip it with small boats for landing. If you need something delivered to your island - hire merchants to do it.

You will never beat an enemy that can kite you
In pretty much any setting, whether it be Ancient Horse Archers, British Frigates, American Stealth Fighters, or some Future Tech Spaceship warfare, there is a certain combination of advantages that will always make an enemy unbeatable.  If you are significantly faster, have a significantly greater effective weapons range, and can reliably see an enemy before it can get into its weapons range, you are able to kite your enemy.  This means you can fire on the enemy while falling back or pursuing them keeping them constantly within your weapons range while staying constantly outside of theirs until you run out of ammo and can simply run away.
Modern Radars and optics: What look like sailing masts are actually giant antenas. Your ship could use Radar and IR to detect distant ships even in fog, rain, or nighttime. This would make your ship virtually impossible to get the drop on while also being able to be tied into your weapon systems for enhanced range engagement.
Modern Propulsion: Modern warships use nuclear powered engines that allow even the largest of warships to out run and out maneuver the most nimble age of sail warships.  While you may look like a sail ship, you can in fact pull a solid 30-40 knots allowing you to outrun even the fastest age of sail ships no matter which way the wind blows.
Modern Weapons: Since there is no good reason to broadside an enemy when you have modern weapons, all those bays on the side of your ship could actually be missile or torpedo bays.  So instead of inaccurate cannons you have to turn your ship to fire, these 36 "guns" could actually be 36 guided weapons that could one-shot kill any age of sail ship from many kilometers away.  Furthermore, you could replace all of your cannonades (swivel guns on the top deck) with 20-30mm autocannons.  While these guns may not look much more impressive than cannonades, using modern ballistics, they can still devastate wooden ships from over 1km away in any direction.
So, by not using one, but many modern technologies in concert, you will have a combination of advantages that will allow your one ship to sink the collective regional naval forces of any foreign nation you might encounter without the risk of leaving any survivors.
Your Advantage is Beyond Belief
The only important thing is to appear like a normal ship when not blowing stuff up.  If you have to blow stuff up, doing it completely, utterly, and with maximum force is the best way to prevent people from believing something is up.
Since dead men tell no tales, and sailors are notorious story tellers anyway, the odds of anyone surviving to tell the tale, and actually being believed, are slim to none.  Infact, with the way that insanity was treated in the 1700s, even if a witness did survive, they'd probably be smart enough to say it was a fleet of 20 privateers or a storm or something. Saying one ship did it, is a good way to get labeled whatever the 1700s equivalent of a UFO conspiracy nut is in the best of cases, or worst case, you are being hauled off to the kind of insane asylum that people go to and are never heard from again.  So, if you want to keep your cover, it is actually best to show off the full array of modern tech and hold nothing back.

This doesn't really fulfil the OP's stated goal of fooling an observer to a ship-to-ship combat.  A torpedo (or even a shell!) would immediately give the game away when fired.  Similarly, diesel or nuclear propulsion would be immediately evident.  (And you couldn't fit even the smallest naval nuclear reactor onto something pretending to be an age-of-sail frigate.  They typically had a length topping out at 150 ft and a displacement of ~1000 tonnes.)

@jdunlop I just updated may answer to account for that detail.  as for nuclear ships, the NR-1 was only 400 tons and 150 ft long.  Modern nuclear technology can be miniaturized to even smaller ships... it just typically isn't.

But the OP specifies third party observer.  So not "a survivor of the attacked ship", but a neutral observer.   Killing everyone on board the target ship is bad enough from the perspective of maintaining the illusion, but killing any neutral observer is almost certainly a fail case.  And the NR-1 was a research submarine with a tiny crew, whereas the faux frigate is going to have to have a convincing crew in addition to its other accoutrements, so you're still not going to have the kind of space you'll need.

(And regarding the insanity cover, if it were one observer, sure, but the crew of an entire Dutch trading vessel, or the crew of a vessel of a different navy?)

@jdunlop The smallest nuclear reactor ever built was the SNAP-10A, which was 40 centimeters long and 23 centimeters wide. There is LOTS of freedom to design reactors to whatever size you need.

Not all reactors are created equal.  SNAP-10A produced enough electricity to drive a washing machine.  Just because you can make a small functional nuclear reactor doesn't mean it'll make the power you need.  If you want to drive a ship of the line, you need a bigger reactor.  And a drive train.  And some way to conceal a screw, unless you're using vectored thrust, which also seems like it would be really hard to disguise.

@jdunlop Some UFO sightings have had over 1000 witnesses, yet people tend to not believe what is unbelievable.  Given human nature and 1700s culture, you will at worst be called a ghost ship.

Also, if there are too many witnesses, you have enough electronics technology to know they are there; so, you can just sail away with moter assistance just fast enough to avoid the fight and just look like a really fast sailing ship.  If you are fast enough, don't have to fight if you don't choose to fight.
